# Plotting by week with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(123)
timeseq <- as.Date(Sys.time() + cumsum(runif(1000)*86400))
data <- rnorm(1000)
df <- data.frame(timeseq,data)
```

I wanted to know if anyone has any methods on how to aggregate `data` by week. What I am attempting to do is plot a time series ggplot, so even better if I can skip this step and have ggplot handle this. Been stuck on this all day.

Comment: Yes a data point for ever week in the date range. The data point represents the sum of rnorm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to manually aggregate by week using dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
df$weeks <- cut(df[,"timeseq"], breaks="week")
agg <- df %>% group_by(weeks) %>% summarise(agg=sum(data))
ggplot(agg, aes(as.Date(weeks), agg)) + geom_point() + scale_x_date() +
    ylab("Aggregated by Week") + xlab("Week") + geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also aggregate a date aesthetic with the `scale_x_date()` function's `breaks` argument.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = timeseq, y = data)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "line") +
    scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d"),
                 breaks = "1 week")
```

Comment: I believe that this only changes the axis labels, rather than aggregating the underlying data.  I was also only able to get this code to work in ggplot2_2.2.1  by changing "breaks" to "date_breaks".

Answer (score 0):

To get the week we can use the `lubridate` library, with the `floor_date` function like so:

```
library(lubridate)
df$week <- floor_date(df$timeseq, "week")
```

We can plot the data using `ggplot` by doing a stats summary (there might be a better way?), and it will look like this:

```
stat_sum_single <- function(fun, geom="point", ...) {
  stat_summary(fun.y=fun, colour="red", geom=geom, size = 3, ...)
}

ggplot(df, aes(x=floor_date(timeseq, "week"), y=data)) + 
  stat_sum_single(sum, geom="line") + 
  xlab("week")
```

which will have the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I want to expand upon @chappers idea of using package `lubridate`, but in a fully piped way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(123)
data.frame(
  timeseq = as.Date(Sys.time() + cumsum(runif(1000) * 86400)),
  data = rnorm(1000)
) %>%
  mutate(timeseq = floor_date(timeseq, unit = "week")) %>%
  group_by(timeseq) %>%
  summarise(data = sum(data)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = timeseq, y = data))
```

Substitute `data.frame` lines with `df` if you have it already stored as an object.